# login status indicator function not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a login status indicator div on my ajax-php database's home page. The login button when clicked does two things.

```
<input value="Login" type="button" onclick='logIntheUser(/*function to process login request*/);updateLoginStatusIndicator(/*function to update login status in login staus indicator div*/);' />
```

> 1. It calls a `logIntheUser` function to send the login data to the php  access
>      processor file to  set `$_SESSION['username']` if user name and
>      password are correct.
> 2. It also calls `updateLoginStatusIndicator` function which displays
>      logged in as `$_SESSION['username']` if `$_SESSION['username']` is set
>      or show  "not logged in" if `$_SESSION['username']` is not set.

Here is the controller code which is executed with `updateLoginStatusIndicator` function:

```
    /*===login status indicator/updater===*/

    if(isset($_REQUEST['change-login-indicator']))
    {
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
    session_start();
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
    echo 'Logged in as:'.$_SESSION['username'];
     }
    else
    {
    echo 'not logged in';
    }
```

Now the problem is that some time the user is logged in successfully(i.e. `$_SESSION['username']` is set) but still the second function `updateLoginStatusIndicator` displays "not logged in". The login status indicator does not work evey time. May be if the `updateLoginStatusIndicator` runs after the `logIntheUser` then it will update login status properly. But I don't know how to do it. Please help!

**EDIT**

When I call the function as callback i.e like: logIntheUser(updateLoginStatusIndicator()), it still does not not work(may be my call back method is incorrect). Then when I add `set_time_limit(1);`  to the `updateLoginStatusIndicator()` function script to delay it for 1 second, it starts to work but its not the best practice to delay the script. Kindly help me how can i work it ou without delay so that `updateLoginStatusIndicator()` function executes only after the `logIntheUser()` function has finished executing. Please help.

Comment: try to do it without using isset function, sometimes isset doesn't work according to the server settings of variables.

Comment: @RavinderSingh hmm its not working that way.I think it due to the timing of the functions execution. It the second function `updateLoginStatusIndicator` run after the first function `logIntheUser` is executed completely then this error will be fixed. But I don't know how to run the first function `logIntheUser`, make the second function `updateLoginStatusIndicator` to wait for the first function to complete and then run it.

Comment: just return some value from the logInTheUser function and call the updateLoginStatusIndicator function when this function returns the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logIntheUser() performs an AJAX request, right? Then the problem with updateLoginStatusIndicator() most likely lies in the fact that if gets called right after the logInTheUser(), not after the AJAX request's successfully finished. That is, it may get the user's status before it's been updated. You should call updateLoginStatusIndicator() in the callbacks for the AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks for the help,You mean I have to use logIntheUset(,,updateLoginStatusIndicator()) right?

Comment: @Exander I called the function as callback i.e like: logIntheUser(,,updateLoginStatusIndicator()) but its still not working(may be my call back method is incorrect). Then I added set_time_limit(1);  to the first function script to delay it for 1 second. With delay its working but its not the best practice to delay the script. Kindly help me how can i work it ou without delay?

Answer (score 1):

Just return some value from the

```
 logInTheUser
```

function and call the

```
 updateLoginStatusIndicator
```

function when this function returns the value

Comment: Please check the edit to my question, I have added more detail. thanks

Comment: just put all the javascript code in a condition that when you will get the value from the first function then only the code below it will execute....

Answer (score 0):

This, in the most cases, happens when an error occurs in the first function. Make sure anything can stop the execution of the script.

**EDIT:**

I suggest you to modify your HTML with a one-function callback on the `onclick` event :

```
onclick="logInProcedure();"
```

And in the JS :

```
function logIntheUser() {

    /* Your code to process login */

    /* set a boolean variable to true or false */

    if(sucessfulyLoggedin) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}

function updateLoginStatusIndicator() {

    /* Your code here */

}


function loginProcedure() {

    if(logIntheUser()) {
        updateLoginStatusIndicator();
    }

}
```

Comment: first function `logIntheUser` is working ok because when I refresh the page the user is logged in successfully.

Comment: Please check the edit to my question, I have added more detail. thanks